# Careers needs a filter for IT staffing firms

Tags: feature-request, jobs

If you look at the [Careers page for Paris](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/explore/paris?f=h) you'll notice that a lot of the places listed aren't cool places to work, they are service companies re-selling developers to other companies. And the same is true for the job listing search.

They are called [IT Staffing firms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_technology_consulting) and really aren't great places to work. Sometimes they provide jobs for customers that are great to work for but that isn't what is listed on their Stack Overflow Careers page, and they nearly never provide this information in Job offers.

Careers should provide a way to filter them and remove them from the view.

And I also think that this filter should be ON by default at least for the cities pages (like Paris). In the current state Careers can't easily be used to distinguish great places to work for.

Some staffing firms can display impressive Joel test results, a beautiful location and great facilities. But if you choose to work for them they will send you out to a client with no good practice, not facilities for employees, etc.

Comment: This comes across as a rant at SSIIs.

Comment: Oh it is partially :D Feel free to edit to keep only the feature request. But the feature is only interesting due to the fact of what SSII are VS how they appear on careers. Without that I don't think that the feature could be useful, it isn't even really useful in countries that don't have so much of them.

Comment: I'd love this filter for the whole internet, even more so for recruitment agencies.